# Android change button style resource on click

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I haven't been able to find quite what I am trying to do on SO, but I feel like it should be such a common interface need that there must be a straightforward way of accomplishing this that I'm missing.

In my style.xml I have two button styles, a standard "active" button and an "inactive" button.

```
<style name="ButtonStandard">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/element_padding</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonInactive">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/element_padding</item>
</style>
```

I am setting one button to `ButtonStandard` and the other to `ButtonInactive`. When I click the inactive button, I want to change it to use the `ButtonStandard` type and vice versa. I don't want to programmatically set the styles individually in case I decide to later change the button styles and it would be unreliable to have to change it in every location.

```
activeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            activeButton.[somehowsetstyle](R.style.ButtonInactive);
            inactiveButton.[somehowsetstyle](R.style.ButtonStandard);
        }
    });
```

How can I change between these styles when users click on buttons? The most important is to not have to set specific styles within the code which is just a last resort imho.

Thanks!

**Solution Notes**

Generally I followed the solution below but instead I created the selector as a drawable and used `android:drawable` instead because it seems the button background needs that, even if just specifying a color. I also used `state_activated` rather than enabled so that it is only changing the look of the button and doesn't prevent clicks.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="false"
      android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
<item android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@color/colorGreen" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorGreen" />
```

**In XML**

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_bkg"
android:state_activated="false"
```

**In Java**

```
myButton.setActivated(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

drawable/my_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@color/enabled_color"/>
    <item android:color="@color/enabled_color"
         android:state_enabled = "true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/disbaled_color"
         android:state_enabled = "false"/>
</selector>
```

my_view.xml

```
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:background="@drawable/my_selector"/>
```

Java code

```
onClick(View v){
    myButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! If I want to change the color of the button as well as the color of the text inside the button, do I need to create two different drawable files?

Comment: The enabled state appears to disable the button entirely so that I can't switch between on or the other once the button is set to disabled.

Comment: Couldn't understand your comment.

Comment: If I set the button to `android:enabled="false"` or ` myButton.setEnabled(true);` the button no longer responds so I can't click on it again to reactivate it and deactivate the other.

Comment: Yeah, that is just an example. Your question was about how to change the style of a view, based on different states. You will have to modify the code as per your requirement.